# Debugging network interaction between iPad and mac mini

Tags: macos, ipad, network, smb

My setup is an iPad (iPadOS 15.3) (8 ft of clear space to the router and a Mac Mini M1 (macOS 12.2) connected to the router via wired ethernet and wifi turned off. Earlier versions of the operating systems had the same problem but seem to have got worse recently)

Connection from either device to the internet and streaming from the internet is fast and reliable.

However I want to play media files stored on my mac mini on an external SSD on my iPad. (Playing these on the Mac Mini is no problem)

This does not work well.

AppleTV takes minutes to load a dozen movies via Home Sharing. Music HomeSharing works but takes a couple of minutes to load.

Plex stalls the video every now and then. It also says sometimes there is not enough band width to play.

Apps that use SMB or Sftp load OK the first time but then get errors trying to play the next movie. e.g. vVideo VLC

The sftp error is the "Timeout waiting for response from sftp subsystem"

The SMB connectiopn provides several errors.  "operation not permitted." "Input/output/error" or in one case rejected my username and password constantly

ssh from iPad to Mac works well.

Where are there useful logs to see what actually happens.

Comment: Rather than chasing SMB and FTP problems, you could run media sharing software on the iMac and a corresponding client on the iPad - I use Plex. Not an answer to your question, but a potential solution for playing media.

Comment: @Gilby I tried Jellyfin and that is slow as well. I also use nVideo which can read DLNA servers and that was not too good - I forget the reasons

Comment: @Gilby so I just got Plex - and bought the ipad client - and watched a tv show and then the client can't find the server. So again how do I debug this

Comment: use Infuse on the iPad. If the video files exclusive mp4 there are several options: FEFileXplorer, FileBrowser Pro, or either of the last plus VLC.

Comment: Actually flex seems to be working now - things like VLC FEFileeXplorer are some of the apps that don't